# Is there any way to make formulae look like handwriting?

Tags: typography

A while back, I saw a question on both Mathematica and MATLAB boards that showed how to 'XKCD' (handwritingnize) graphs. Now I have the same question regarding LaTeX formulae generally - is it possible to make them look handwritten?

Comment: Can you add pointers?

Comment: Can you maybe also give an idea of the quality of handwriting you're looking to emulate? I've had professors who had impeccable style when writing formulas on the blackboard -- the resulting equations looked like they were typeset. The handwriting of some other professors doesn't compare favorably with chicken scratch. (I politely refuse to discuss my own handwriting...) Where in the spectrum of possible handwriting styles would you like to land?

Comment: Wouldn't it only be possible to the extent that a 'handwritten' font had the mathematical symbols you need for your formulae?  There is an [xkcd font](https://github.com/ipython/xkcd-font), but it probably lacks many symbols you'd want to use.

Comment: the "euler cursive" font (included in the `amsfonts` collection) was designed to emulate writing on a blackboard, but it contains only letters and digits.  (and, of course, hermann zapf's handwriting is much more elegant than that of most of the professors i had classes with.)  maybe another place to start.

Comment: Yesterday evening I look Leonardo De Wince learning channel show about Gutenberg and it grandeurs achievement to print first 180 copies of Bible. So, wondering. why someone need to go back to before Gutenberg era and imitate handwriting? At least in text with since, scholar, engineering backgrounds this less relevant in comparison to contents of text. If it is difficulty to understand, why I need to gives unnecessary effort for reading it? Well, another story is, if I write love letter ... :-)

Comment: The Euler font is supposed to be modeled after how mathematicians wrote on a black board. An extended Opentype version of the font is available on github as NeoEuler

Comment: @Zarko “Leonardo De Wince”? I know “Leonardo da Vinci”. `;-)`